# Are people allowed to mention paying somebody?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/192059/magento-2-base-price-with-currency) originally had a comment about paying somebody for help, I removed the comment as I'm not sure if it's allowed or not.

What are the rules for this?

I feel it shouldn't be allowed, the answers here should be public for all to see.

Comment: Related discussion on main meta: [Edit out an offer of financial reward. Right or wrong?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/42767)

Answer (score 8):

Job hunting and developer fishing are not allowed